# Angular routing not working on refresh in Azure App Service

Tags: angular, azure-web-app-service

I have an Angular v16 application with various routes, for example 'user/:recordId'.

If I try and navigate director to test.co.uk/user/1 this works correctly when I am using the default domain created in azure (test.co.uk) in the example above. However, if I setup a custom domain for my web app and to the same thing, for example test2.co.uk/user/1. It seems unable to find the route and instead falls back to test2.co.uk default page.

There is no difference in configuration, its the same app but being access from 2 different domains, only the default domain ever seems to refresh correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error is related to the configs in the web.config file for IIS, just check if the configs are written properly for the test2.co.uk deployment.

you can refer to [Deploy Ng App to IIS](https://angularindepth.com/posts/1239/deploy-an-angular-application-to-iis)